# Presenting a ViewController breaks the previous ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

My problem is when I present a `UIViewController` the presenting views are going black.

I have a `UIViewController` named `mainViewController` which is the root view of my windows.
Inside I have a `MMDrawerController` (just added as a subview of mainViewController's view).

The `MMDrawerController` contains the rest of my views.

But when I'm presenting a new `UIViewController` from my `mainViewController`, the new VC displays well, but when it dismisses it left only black screen behind.
To note the black screen appears when adding (I can see it directly). Not when dismissing.

For testing purpose I did this code :

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:vc animated:NO completion:^{
    [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

Which do the same black result as normal use. (normally it's a `QLViewController`...)

My mainViewController is set like it :

```
_mainViewController = [MyMainViewController new];
_window.rootViewController = _mainViewController;
[self.window addSubview:_mainViewController.view];
```

[Souce code of MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) which is up to date in my project

Comment: What version of iOS are you building for? Have you considered using storyboards rather than creating assigning your rootViewController in code?

Comment: @AshleyMills I build for iOS 6 and 7, I didn't try on iOS6 for this problem, it happens on iOS7 (which I care the most...).
I never use IB in all the app (and won't use, it shouldn't be anything to do with the solution).

Comment: I tested in a new project with the code you written, but the mainViewController remain the backgroundcolor

Comment: @simalone problem is not with the *mainViewController* which seems fine. It's with other UIViewController in (`MMDrawerController`). When I present my new `UIViewController`, my previous one (which was already in *mainViewController*) is broken, like its constraints are totally gone. And I don't see it anymore on screen (but it is still a subview I guess).

Comment: @AncAinu so the problem maybe in MMDrawerController implement code, can you list main code about it?

Comment: @simalone [Souce code of MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

Comment: Have you tried getting the window from AppDelegate instead of [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]?

Comment: @P.Sami yep, I did it directly with my *mainViewController* too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem was that I applied inset constraints on my *mainViewController*.

Behind the scene I suppose that method `presentViewController:animated:completion:` use frames and not AutoLayout, which break the `UIView` of the `UIViewController` that are in the *mainViewController*.

Thanks to @simalone, I used the same way to find the origin of the problem (use `MMDrawerController` example project).

I you want to test yourself the problem, [I uploaded the example project with the issue](http://dl.free.fr/rm.pl?h=jlnjvw1dP&i=64438166&s=hYVm0VGYktP2krro4fipwQiRRCwSE9aO) so you can understand it.
There is a breakpoint on the line which is the origin of the bug.
Then just double click on the view.

Thanks again to @simalone. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the code just in MMDrawerController example project, but I can't reproduce the problem, following is what I have tried:

MMAppDelegate.m

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{
    //...

    UIViewController *testVc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    testVc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [testVc.view addSubview:self.drawerController.view];

    [self.window setRootViewController:testVc];
    [self.window addSubview:testVc.view];

    return YES;
}
```

MMExampleSideDrawerViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case MMDrawerSectionViewSelection:{
            UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
            vc.view.backgroundColor  = [UIColor redColor];
            UIViewController *mainVC =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
            [mainVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
                [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            }];

            return;
    //...
}
```

MMExampleCenterTableViewController.m:

```
-(void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture{
    UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
    vc.view.backgroundColor  = [UIColor redColor];
    UIViewController *mainVC =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController;
    [mainVC presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{
        [vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

    return;

    [self.mm_drawerController bouncePreviewForDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You put me in the right direction dude. I found the problem.